# (ng)quill problem: the selected value of custom font family/size is not displayed in ql-picker-label

Tags: angularjs, quill

We have added the ng-quill component to our web app build with angularjs. With the code below my developer tried to customize font family and font size picker in the toolbar.  It is functional so far but the selected value of the dropdown options is not displayed after selection. "Sans serif" and "normal" keep to be displayed.

Here the code:

```
    (function () {
'use strict';

 angular
     .module('tu.richtext.editor', ['ngQuill'])
         .constant('NG_QUILL_CONFIG', {
             modules:   {
                 toolbar: [
                     ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
                     ['blockquote', 'code-block', 'link'],
                     [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],
                     [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
                     [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],
                     [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
                     [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],
                     [{ 'size': [false, '14px', '16px', '18px', '20px'] }],
                     [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, false] }],
                     [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
                     [{ 'font': ['sans-serif', 'times-new-roman', 'roboto', 'lato', 'oswald', 'montserrat', 'raleway', 'lora', 'nunito', 'prompt'] }],
                     [{ 'align': [] }],
                     ['clean'],
                     ['link', 'image', 'video']
                 ]
             },
             theme: 'snow',
             placeholder: '',
             readonly: false,
             bounds: document.body
         })
         .config(function(ngQuillConfigProvider, NG_QUILL_CONFIG) {
             ngQuillConfigProvider.set(NG_QUILL_CONFIG);
             // ngQuillConfigProvider.set(null, null, 'custom placeholder');
         })
         .component('tuRichtextEditor', {
             bindings: {
                 ngModel: '=',
                 required: '<',
                 format: '<'
             },
             controller: RichtextEditorCtrl,
             controllerAs: '$ctrl',
             templateUrl: 'app-commons/components/tu-richtext-editor/tuRichText.tpl.html'
         });

 function RichtextEditorCtrl($scope, $timeout, $sce) {

     var ctrl = this;
     ctrl.loadComplete = false;

     ctrl.customOptions = [{
         import: 'attributors/style/size',
         whitelist: [false, '14px', '16px', '18px', '20px']
     }, {
         import: 'attributors/class/font',
         whitelist: ['sans-serif', 'times-new-roman', 'roboto', 'lato', 'oswald', 'montserrat', 'raleway', 'lora', 'nunito', 'prompt']
     }];

     $scope.customModules = {
         toolbar: [
             [{'size': [false, '14', '16', '18', '20']}]
         ]
     };

     ctrl.$onInit = function () {
         // console.log(Quill);
         // console.log(ctrl.ngModel);

         ctrl.readOnly = false;
         ctrl.required = ctrl.required? 'required' : '';

         registerDelegates();
     };

     function registerDelegates() {
         ctrl.editorCreated = function (editor) {
             console.log(editor);
             console.log(editor.editor);
         };

         ctrl.contentChanged = function (editor, html, text, content, delta, oldDelta, source) {
             ctrl.ngModel = html;
         };

         ctrl.selectionChanged = function (editor, range, oldRange, source) {
             console.log('editor: ', editor, 'range: ', range, 'oldRange:', oldRange, 'source:', source);
         };

         ctrl.loadComplete = true;
     }
 }})();
```

The css classes are changed too regarding to these examples:

```
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-item[data-value="14px"]::before  {content: '14'; font-size: 14px !important;}

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value="roboto"]::before {content: 'Roboto'; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important; }
```

He had given up now and I have not been able to find the bug.

Comment: Maybe I discovered today an imortant part of the problem: the dev tools show me that for our font family and font size custom values in the quill.snow.css file no classes are defined. Absolutely correct, I think. But where do we have to add these classes to be used instaed of the default classes with the content "Sans Serif" and "Normal" if a custom value is selected?

Comment: I solved it by myself. The correrct label picker css classes have been missing.

Comment: Can you please explain that how to resolved it as i am facing same issue?

Comment: Sorry, my trial to show you my solution was deleted by Samuel Liew. I do not know which rules I have broken with that posting. May be he can help you the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Quill has an example for how to use custom fonts:
https://quilljs.com/playground/#custom-fonts

You can add custom sizes the same way.

Comment: I used same process..Initially it was worked but after upgradation on angular version it stopped working.

Comment: @EktaShukla have you got the answer for the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889006/primeng-quill-editor-custom-font-size-setting-issue-with-angular-9?